# How to prevent jQuery UI effect from triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I'm trying to use the [highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect from jQuery UI to show the user an explanation corresponding to some radio button choices. But the effect triggers twice, i.e. the relevant page component flashes twice instead of once.

I've had a look at similar questions, but they either have [solutions that don't apply to my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423235/jquery-event-triggering-twice-for-no-reason) or have a [solution that doesn't work in my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286211/jquery-ui-effect-double-triggers-event). (Or the answers/comments ask for more details or an example which is never given.)

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaamos/a7kRB/1/) with a simplified version of my problem.

If you click on one of the radio buttons, the corresponding paragraph flashes green twice. As you can see from the JS section, the solution proposed in the second link above (using `.off('click').on('click')` to prevent the "cloning" effect) doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm using jQuery 1.8.0 and jQuery UI 1.8.22 (jsfiddle uses 1.7.2 and 1.8.18, respectively, and has the same issue) and the same thing happens on Opera, Chrome, and Firefox.

How can I work around this and have the effect only execute once? Happy to use a workaround if there is one...

Comment: when i click on the first radio, the first paragraph flash one time as expected..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that 2 click events are triggered, once for the `label` and once for the `input`. This is because a click on the label 'triggers' a click on the input. Change your selectors to prevent this:

```
    $('#labelChoice1 input').click(function(e) {
        highlightDiv(1);
    });
    $('#labelChoice2 input').click(function(e) {
        highlightDiv(2);
    });
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a7kRB/2/).

Comment: Thanks heaps, that solution and the explanation was exactly what I was after :-)

Answer (score 2):

A more extensible version might look like this:

```
function highlightDiv(index) {
    $('p#explanation' + index).effect("highlight", {color: '#00ff00'}, 1000);
}

$(':radio').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        // zero-based index
        highlightDiv(i + 1);      
    });
});
​
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/a7kRB/5/**

Comment: I wanted to get it to work first before refactoring it for more radio buttons, but your code will save me that effort, cheers :-)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you'd take setting up the click functions out of the document ready event, by the way?

Comment: It's implied that all code manipulating the DOM should be in an onReady callback, so it's purely to reduce the amount of code the in the example.

Comment: Gotcha, was just wondering because I noticed you'd moved it out in the jsfiddle as well. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work just fine

```
$('#labelChoice2').on('click', '#choice2', function() {
    highlightDiv(2);
});
```

the second parameter basically just says on which sub children of #labelChoice2 the method should apply, trying it on jsfiddle shows that this solution works

Comment: I'll go with Sidharth's solution and a version of Matt's refactoring, but thanks for another useful option, I didn't know you could specify that parameter.